# An inequality about curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\alpha:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ be a regular parametrized plane curve. Assume that there exists $t_0$, $a<t_0<b,$ such that the distance $|\alpha (t)|$ from the origin to the trace of $\alpha$ will be a maximum at $t_0$. Prove that the curvature $k$ of $\alpha$ at $t_0$ satisfies $k(t_0)\geq1/|\alpha(t_0)|$.

I am confused about how to use the condition "the distance $|\alpha (t)|$ from the origin to the trace of $\alpha$ will be a maximum at $t_0$". Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By regular I assume that $\alpha$ is two times differentiable with respect to the arc length $t$. Since $f(t):=|\alpha(t)|^2$ reaches a maximum at $t_0$ in the interior of $[a,b]$, then the second derivative at $t_0$ is negative. We have 
$$f'(t)=2\left\langle \alpha'(t),\alpha(t)\right\rangle$$
and 
$$f''(t)=2\left\langle\alpha''(t),\alpha(t)\right\rangle+2|\alpha'(t)|^2$$
so 
$$1=|\alpha'(t_0)|^2<- \left\langle\alpha''(t_0),\alpha(t_0)\right\rangle\leqslant \left|\alpha''(t_0)\right|\cdot \left|\alpha \left(t_0\right)\right|,$$
and we get the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I was wondering how do you think of using the second derivative of $|\alpha(t)|^2?$

Comment: We know that the curvature is expressed thanks to the second derivative of $\alpha$ and the square is here to make the expression easier to differentiate.

Comment: Yes... And why $|\alpha'(t_0)|^2=1$?

Comment: I guess it's an assumption about $\alpha$ (regular) (we want a constant speed).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What is the curvature of the circle of radius $\vert\alpha(t_0)\vert$ centered at the origin?